# Link error /Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, linker-errors

I have problem with Xcode, keeps giving me a linker error, and it doesn't build the project. The following is the error am getting

> ld: file not found:
>   /Users/someuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MAR-akbwbarcniqxytctbebckkelkbxs/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/MAR.app/MAR
>
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

Comment: Menu >> Product >> Clean and try again...

Comment: had to tick on rosetta

Answer (score 68):

As some of the fellow developers have mentioned here, the root cause of the error was "Change in Product Name". I fixed it by :

1. Go to [project]Tests -> general
2. Select Host Application

   [image]

Credits : https://stackoverflow.com/a/28906400/2164029

Comment: Thank you. I've wasted hours on this.

Comment: This was the cause of the issue for me too.

Comment: Great. This resolve my issue. I had changed app name.

Comment: Thank you. Spent 4 hours trying to figure this out!

Comment: Savior for the day! Gracias

Answer (score 15):

I picked up a project that had this same error.  I found that the project name had changed, but the code I had did not reflect that change in the project build settings.  To correct, I updated the "Product Name" value (found under targets | Packaging) to the correct value and rebuilt the project.  Ran fine.

Comment: I have been working at this problem for the past 6hrs strait and this is the only thing that fixed it THANK YOU! What I did was delete the product name and product module name then retype them exactly the same. Somehow it fixed it.

Answer (score 8):

I got this fixed by selecting the Tests target and searching for Bundle Loader in Build Settings and changing the product name in that path. I got this error because I have changed the Product name. The Bundle loader has the old product name in the path, so it searches for that path.

Answer (score 8):

I had the exact same problem and if you are using cocoapods make sure you open your project with `.xcworkspace` not `.xcodeproj`, for me it was that simple.

Answer (score 2):

Make a deep clean of your project by `⌘ Clean` (Menu >> Product >> Clean)

Answer (score 2):

I solved by running **pod deintegrate** https://github.com/CocoaPods/cocoapods-deintegrate:

`pod deintegrate`

`pod install`

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, I have removed what ever was in dependency.
Build Phases -> target dependancies
remove whatever in there.
if there's test target also click on the test in the build phases in the target dependancies remove what ever in there.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up resolving this in Xcode 7.3 by *deleting* the **Bundle Loader** values under Build Settings. Seemed risky, but I noticed the other targets didn't have any such values defined; only the test targets (which were failing to build due to this error).

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue. What I did was to look for a different 'Product Name' listed under Build Settings. I found the old Product Name still listed under Packaging (Both the Product Name and Product Module Name had the old name). I changed it to the new one and the project compiled without error.