# Apple Mach-O Linker Error, after changing project name

Tags: swift, xcode, error-handling, linker

I'm making an app in Xcode 6.1.1, and just changed the name of the app, and afterwards I'm getting this *"Apple Mach-O Linker Error"* build failed error. 
It says *"ld: file not found:"*, probably because it can't find the placement of some file with the new name.. Any suggestions?

> ld: file not found: /Users/rb/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Which_Club-gkgjdxflldelikaopinkdoskkers/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/WhichClubToUse.app/WhichClubToUse
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

"Which_club" is the new name of the project, and "WhichClubToUse" is the old name..

Comment: I remember having the same error but I don't know what exactly I had to do - maybe try to clean the project once?

Comment: And how do you clean it? (Noob here)

Comment: Go to -> Product -> Clean or use cmd + alt + K

Comment: hmm that didnt work, just got the same error message again :-(

Comment: For me this problem was not reliably reproducible. It would occur with only one of my test targets, about 75% of the time. The accepted answer does seem to fix it though.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found the solution! Under my [project]Tests -> general, i needed to select the new Host Application

Comment: Thanks for saving me 2 hours.

Comment: @Pattay No problem :-)